# selenium click functions working randomly

Tags: selenium

I have selenium click functions implemented by .click(), .by Actions, and by JS. None of them works stable, in other words, they work sometimes, and do not some other times. I also used Sleep functions. It is really painful. I am using selenium-server-standalone-2.52.0.jar

Can anyone give me an idea on how to solve the problems. Thanks a lot.

Charlie

Comment: Perhaps you could share what you've done so far and what's the page against which you're running the test? Otherwise we're just left guessing what could possibly be wrong.

Comment: Try to put isdisplayed() function before clicking on the webelement. And if it is displayed then it will definately click on it if not, then the element is not visible due to wrong xpath selection. it might be dynamic xpath change the xpath instead.

Comment: It is a bank page, the page source has just normal HTML tags. I tried isDisplayed etc functions. still unstable.

Comment: got some workaround? I am in same situation?

Comment: I used JNI code (C++ dll using SetPortVal() ) to simulate key strokes, but not mouse clicks after taking focus. I think it is the same.  The problem in my case is it is not practical as I have lots of concurrences.

Answer (score 0):

Your element is probably not loaded properly while getting error. You'd better use explicit wait in your script. Wait until your specific element loaded to be visible/clickable. I think, this may help you.

**Code snippet:**

```
    By yourElementToSelect = By.id("elementID"); // you may use cssSelector or any other locator you wish
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(yourElementToSelect));         
    driver.findElement(yourElementToSelect).click();
```